# Check if name already exist

Tags: php, sql, database

I have this code.

This code can check if form number is already existing in the database.

Now i want to check if the firstname and lastname is already existing.what and where should i

```
$FNresult = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM profile WHERE FormNo = '$FrmN' ");
if (!$FNresult) {
    die(mysql_error());
}
if (mysql_result($FNresult, 0, 0) > 0) {
    echo "<br>Form number already exist!";
}
else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO profile 
                (FormNo, FirstName, LastName, Address, Email, MobileNo, 
                 LandlineNo, Amount, Term, Manner)
                VALUES ('$FrmN', '$FN', '$LN', '$ADD', '$E', '$MOBILE', 
                        '$LAND', '$AMNT', '$TRM', '$MNNR')";

    if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
    {
          die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    echo "<br>1 record added!";
}
mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: Use `mysql_num_rows()` - or `mysqli_num_rows()` or PDO's `rowCount()` then drop the `COUNT(*)` when using these, and select the said column(s).

Comment: i don't where and how.i'am a beginner

Comment: See the answer below. However, make sure your DB connection is `mysqli_` and not `mysql_`. Those two functions do not mix together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$sql = mysqli_query("SELECT firstname,lastname FROM profile WHERE firstname = '$firstname' and lastname = '$lastname'");

$rownum = mysqli_num_rows($sql);

if( $rownum > 0 )
    die('Your name already exists in database');
```

Note = I wrote `mysqli_*` but you are using `mysql_*`

You can change it depending on how you want it to be.

You should change your `mysql_*` to `mysqli_*` as the first one has been deprecated and will be deleted in the future

Something similar to the code above must do the trick.

Good Luck

Comment: You're missing a few ending semi-colons.

Comment: You're welcome. Have +1 - However, OP may required additional help. Says is beginner.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Op can ask more question in case he can't do it with the mentioned code

Comment: OP can place comments under your answer if something is unclear.

Comment: Yes yes by asking more questions i mean comments :D